# Random walk code in python [2 dimensions]

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

Please could you help me by figuring out what is the wrong with my code.
I am trying to write a program that generates random walks in two dimensions and that determines statistics about the position of the walker after 500 steps when the number of walks is 1000, the max step size is 0.9, and the separation between the two positions is 0.001.

```
import math
import random
import time

print "RANDOM WALKS ANALYSIS IN ONE DIMENSION"
NOFW_ = 1000 #The number of walks 
NOFS_= 500 #The number of steps in each walk
MSS_ = 0.9 # The maximum step size[m]
SOFP_ = 0.001  # The separation of positions considered equal[m]

print "                         Number of walks: %3g"% NOFW_
print "            Number of steps in each Walk: %3g"% NOFS_
print "                       Maximum step size: %3g"% MSS_,"m"
print "Separation of positions considered equal: %3g"% SOFP_,"m"
print
print "Please wait while random walks are generated and analyzed..."
print "Date:" + time.ctime()
print

def initialPosition():
    return (0.0, 0.0)

def distance(posA, posB):
    """Calculates the distance between two positions posA and posB"""
    distance = math.sqrt((posB[0] - posA[0])**2 + (posB[1] - posA[1])**2)
    return distance

def printstats(description, numbers):
    minimum_value_ = min(numbers) 
    numbers.sort()
    Tenth_percentile = abs(0.10*len(numbers) + 0.5)
    Mean_value_ = (1./float(len(numbers))*sum(numbers))
    A = 0
    for values in numbers:
        B = distance(values, Mean_value_)
        B = B**2
        A = B + A
    Standard_deviation = math.sqrt((1./(len(numbers)-1))*A)
    Newposition_ = int(0.90*(len(numbers) + 0.5))
    Ninetieth_percentile =numbers[Newposition_]
    maximum_value_ = max(numbers)

    print "Analysis for"""+ description
    print "Minimum value: %9.1f" % minimum_value_
    print "10th percentile: %7.1f" % Tenth_percentile
    print "Mean value: %12.1f" % Mean_value_
    print "Standard deviation: %4.1f" % Standard_deviation
    print "90th percentile: %7.1f" % Ninetieth_percentile
    print "Maximum value: %9.1f" % maximum_value_


    list_1 = [minimum_value_, Tenth_percentile, Mean_value_, Standard_deviation, Ninetieth_percentile,maximum_value_]
    return list_1

def takeStep(prevPosition, maxStep):
    x = random.random()
    y = random.random() 
    minStep = -maxStep
    Z = random.random()*2*math.pi
    stepsize_ = random.random()*0.9
    Stepx= stepsize_*math.cos(Z)
    Stepy= stepsize_*math.sin(Z)
    New_positionx = prevPosition[0] + Stepx
    New_positiony = prevPosition[1] + Stepy
    return (New_positionx, New_positiony) 

Step_100 = []
Step_500 = []
count_list = []
for walk in range(NOFW_):
    Step1 = []
    Position = (0.0,0.0)
    count = 0
    for step in range(NOFS_):
        Next_Step_ = takeStep(Position, MSS_)
        for word in Step1:
            if distance(Next_Step_, word) <= SOFP_:
                count +=1 
        position = Next_Step_
        Step1.append(Next_Step_)
    Step_100.append(Step1[-1])
    Step_500.append(Step1[-1])
    count_list.append(count)

Step_100 = printstats("distance from start at step 100 [m]", Step_100)
Step_500 = printstats("distance from start at step 500 [m]", Step_500)
count_list = printstats("times position revisited", count_list)
```

Comment: the code does not give the required result when I run it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
Mean_value_ = (1./float(len(numbers))*sum(numbers))
```

`sum()` is supposed to get some numbers but your variable `numbers` is actually containing some tuples of 2 values

You may want to define your own sum function for tuples of 2 numbers, or to sum the first values and second values separately

Comment: @AhmedAli as said, it, depends, your mean value is the mean of the distances compared to your starting point ?